# php search and replace

Tags: php

I am trying to create a database field merge into a document (rtf) using php

i.e if I have a document that starts

Dear Sir,

Customer Name: [customer_name], Date of order: [order_date]

After retrieving the appropriate database record I can use a simple search and replace to insert the database field into the right place.

So far so good.

I would however like to have a little more control over the data before it is replaced. For example I may wish to Title Case it, or convert a delimited string into a list with carriage returns.

I would therefore like to be able to add extra formatting commands to the field to be replaced. e.g.

Dear Sir,

Customer Name: [customer_name, TC], Date of order: [order_date, Y/M/D]

There may be more than one formatting command per field.

Is there a way that I can now search for these strings? The format of the strings is not set in stone, so if I have to change the format then I can.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a RegEx and [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function replace_param($matches)
{
  $parts = explode(',',$matches[0]);
  //$parts now contains an array like: customer_name,TC,SE,YMD
  // do some substitutions and:
  return $text;
}
preg_replace_callback('/\[([^\]]+)\]/','replace_param',$rtf);
```

Comment: Josh, thanks, that looks really interesting, and the sort of thing that I was after. Will this parse the whole file finding multiple matches, or will I have to do some sort of looping?

Comment: I believe that will find every match calling replace_param() on each one.

Comment: Thanks, I've given it a test and it works well. I got an error to start with and found that I needed to use forward slashes around the regex i.e.

preg_replace_callback('/\[([^\]]+)\/]','replace_param',$rtf);

Comment: That was a silly mistake on my part, sorry! I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a templating system like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net), that might make your life easier, as you can do `{$customer_name|ucwords}` or actually put PHP code in your email template.

Comment: That sound like the sort of functionality I require, but I'm not outputting the document, but putting it back into a rtf editor. Are there any classes that would do this?

Comment: You could use smarty with output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` on it to separate them into array values.

For Example:

```
$customer_name = 'customer_name, TC';
$get_fields = explode(',', $customer_name);

foreach($get_fields as $value)
{
  $new_val = trim($value);
  // Now do whatever you want to these in here.
}
```

Sorry if I'm not understanding you.

Comment: my problem is I don't know what to explode as it will change dynamically, I may have 'customer_name, TC' or 'customer_name, UC' or something completely different. I was wondering whether I could search for some sort of matching brackets?